# select rows where only 1 of boolean columns is true

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with the following format:

```sql
CREATE TABLE segments(id INT, walk BOOLEAN, taxi BOOLEAN, bus BOOLEAN,
     subway BOOLEAN, bike BOOLEAN);

INSERT INTO segments (id, walk, taxi, bus, subway, bike)
VALUES (0,false,false,false,false,true),
(1,true,true,false,false,false),(2,true,false,false,false,false),
(3,true,false,true,false,false),(4,true,true,true,false,false),
(5,false,false,true,false,false),(6,true,true,false,false,false),
(7,true,false,false,false,false),(8,true,false,true,false,false),
(9,true,true,true,false,false),(10,true,false,true,false,false);

SELECT * FROM segments;
id  walk    taxi    bus     subway  bike
0    f       f       f        f      t
1    t       t       f        f      f
2    t       f       f        f      f
3    t       f       t        f      f
4    t       t       t        f      f
5    f       f       t        f      f
6    t       t       f        f      f
7    t       f       f        f      f
8    t       f       t        f      f
9    t       t       t        f      f
10   t       f       t        f      f
```

But I want filter rows where only 1 of walk, taxi, bus, subway or bike it true, and no other.

Expected output:

```
id  walk    taxi    bus     subway  bike
0    f       f       f        f      t
2    t       f       f        f      f
5    f       f       t        f      f
7    t       f       f        f      f
```

Comment: if you had used a BYTE or INT data type you could have used walk+taxi+bus+...=1
I don't know postgresql but I thought that boolean were not part of SQL standard. I think they don't exist in the major engines (oracle/sql server). Getting old surely

Comment: I see, the table was designed this way, I only have read-only access. The example is to replicate existing table.

Comment: Boolean is part of sqlstandard these days, T031 in sql-2016. Not sure if it existed before that also

Comment: FWIW, T031 appears for the first time in SQL99

Comment: Microsoft SQL-Server introduced it in SQL2012,  IBM Db2 in 11.5 and I havent found it for Oracle yet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can cast boolean as int in postgres:

```
SELECT *
from segments
where walk::int + taxi::int + bus::int + subway::int + bike::int = 1;
```

| id | walk | taxi | bus | subway | bike |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | false | false | false | false | true |
| 2 | true | false | false | false | false |
| 5 | false | false | true | false | false |
| 7 | true | false | false | false | false |

See [db fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8Dsm2BK8mzbFSWFWLELgkJ/0).

Comment: I feel like an idiot now;-)

Comment: @Lennart-SlavaUkraini You get the creative solution award.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to encode your booleans as bits, and then check that exactly 1 bit is set. Example:

```
select * from segments
where 1*walk::int+2*taxi::int+4*bus::int+8*subway::int+16*bike::int in (1,2,4,8,16);
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/UjtdJGGE)